# Emberjs - Ember.Select valueBinding fails to work

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a simple Ember.Select and I'd like to use the valueBinding option.

Changing The select value should changed the displayed value above. It does not.

http://jsfiddle.net/mattkime/rDpEG/

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean `selectionBinding` and it binds the object so use `{{App.power.label}}`

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    App Power : {{#if App.power}}{{App.power.label}}{{else}}Not yet set{{/if}}
    <hr/>
        {{view Ember.Select
        contentBinding="App.booleanOptions"
        selectionBinding="App.power"
        optionLabelPath="content.label"
        optionValuePath="content.value"
        id="emberEnhanced"
      }}
</script>
```

Comment: +1, FYI, you can avoid the if statement in the template by initialize App.power to null. http://jsfiddle.net/rDpEG/2/

Comment: That is a useful info, I didnt notice that :)

Answer (score 1):

looks like i'm inquiring about a yet to be released feature. The current release is 0.9.8.1 and valueBinding is in trunk

Comment: By the way, did you check this my answer? illustrated with this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rDpEG/1/